# Passing undefined data to React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a realtime dashboard which consumes an API for the data. The application is an isomorphic react app built on top of a node API, I am using the Flux architecture, more specifically the [alt implementation](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt).

On initial page load I call `componentDidMount` and pass the action to fetch data

```
componentDidMount() {
   MyActions.getData();
   MyStore.listen(this._onChange);
}
```

As this is calling an external API there is a delay in fetching the data, this means the state which will house the data is `undefined`. In order to stop the component erroring as I would be passing `undefined` data I am currently doing the following:

```
render() {

   let foo;

   if(typeof this.state.apiData == "undefined") {
       foo = (<div></div>
    } else {
        foo = (<MyComponent data={this.state.apiData} />)
    );
}
```

Although this works it doesn't feel very elegant, is there a better way to catch `undefined` data before rendering components?

Answer (score 1):

what you could do is use `componentWillMount()` to start fetching the data. and the check you are doing in your `render()` function could look like:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.apiData === undefined) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <MyComponent data={this.state.apiData} />
  );
}
```

Also as you mentioned that you data changes it might be worth to make use of [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) to check for changes and rerender if needed